# inductive reasoning pattern (1 of 2)

Tags: pattern

In a practice test on [this website](https://www.shldirect.com/en/practice-tests/) I found a pattern that I cannot figure out.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> A

---

Explanation:

> The arrow's position is cyclic with cycle $4$: up-down-left-right so the fifth square must contain an up arrow. Option B is eliminated.

> There is a small square surrounding a circle every $2$ squares (cycle $2$) so there wouldn't be a square surrounding any circle for the fifth square. Option E is eliminated.

> Finally, we see that there are two white circles in the first, two grey circles in the second, and this cycle of $2$ repeats. Hence there will be two white circles in the fifth square. Options C and D are eliminated.

Comment: In your third argument, You mean two white circles?

Comment: @shamalaia Yes. Edited :)